# Updating and keeping a value in an input tag

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to write a simple javascript program, which updates the value of an **input type="hidden"**.

In my script, a particular value gets changed too often, so I'm trying to use the below method to store the previous value.

```
<input type="hidden" value="" id="test">

<script>
alert(document.getElementById('test').value);
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML=10;
alert(document.getElementById('test'));
</script>
```

10 doesn't gets stored. How can I make it work ?
My prime motive is, to have the previous value (**And the last n values changed**), and updated value at the same time. If there are any other methods to obtain this required task, I'd be happy to listen.

Comment: Your first alert gets the `value`, the second the `element`

Comment: Do you only want the last two values or last n values as you keep updating?

Comment: @srrvnn
The last n values are required.

Comment: Have you tried using two hidden variables, one to store prev value and one to store next value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example:

```
alert(document.getElementById('test').value);
document.getElementById('test').value = "10";
alert(document.getElementById('test').value);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HTq8J/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="" id="test">

<script>
  alert(document.getElementById('test').value);
  document.getElementById('test').value = '10';
  alert(document.getElementById('test').value);
</script>
```

Comment: you forgot the value in last alert